# Как пищать системной пищалкой?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Видел, что от windows 7 это делать нельзя. Можно пример кода хотя бы на xp или linux?

ОС: windows 10 и linux mint
IDE: Code::Blocks

Comment: `Beep` от Windows вас не устраивает?

Comment: `cout << '\a';`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4060601/5045688

Answer (score 1):

`\a` - a = alert. это управляющий символ ANSI для звукового сигнала. 
Поэтому `cout << '\a';` издает звук boop. Если этот символ послать на принтер или на терминал, то ничего не напечатается, но послышится звуковой сигнал.

Английское название - BELL

Comment: Только работает это не во всех эмуляторах терминала

Comment: На Windows 10 не работает

Comment: @Никита `#include <Windows.h>
void beep() {
  Beep(440, 1000);
}` 
работает?

Comment: Нет. Функция возвращает 1

Comment: @Никита https://ideone.com/nEC8qW так пробовали?

Comment: пробовал, не работает